# How to declare custom types in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, types

I want to declare a custom data type for better code readability. The intent is to keep this type clean from any interference with other AnsiStrings. But Delphi seems to not support it?

```
type
  TKMLocaleCode = type AnsiString;

... snip ...

procedure A;
var 
  A,B: TKMLocaleCode;
  C: AnsiString; 
begin
  A := 'eng'; //<<-- I expect an error here
  A := C; //<<-- I expect an error here too

  B := TKMLocaleCode('eng'); //<<-- I expect no error here
end;
```

Is it possible to declare such a custom type in Delphi?

Comment: Type **of** AnsiString? I don't think that's a valid declaration to begin with.

Comment: @RobKennedy I never saw`Type of AnsiString` before, but since it compiles omitting the comparision, just for interest what would it be? The debugger does not really help in analyzing ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't have gotten an error where you did, but your initial technique wouldn't accomplish your goal anyway. Notice how `TFileName` is a distinct string type just like yours, but it can be used anywhere an ordinary string is expected. The `type` declaration is more for establishing different RTTI for a type so that it can be used for different kinds of property editors at design time.

To really make a distinct type, try declaring a record with a field to hold your data. Records are not compatible with anything else, even when they have the same structure as another type. To make your record comparable with other values of the same type, overload the comparison operator by providing `Equal` and `NotEqual` methods in the record declaration. To allow creation of the distinct type through type casting, but not through ordinary assignment, provide an `Explicit` operator, but not `Implicit`.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a record and then use operator overloading to supply whichever operators you wish to support:

```
type
  TKMLocaleCode = record
  strict private
    FValue: AnsiString;
  public
    class operator Explicit(const Value: string): TKMLocaleCode;
  end;

class operator TKMLocaleCode.Explicit(const Value: AnsiString): TKMLocaleCode;
begin
  Result.FValue := Value;
end;
```

Clearly you'll want to add more functionality, but this record meets the requirements stated in the question.